# Alternative to using hidden fields in Rails. Keeping things secure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am setting up a system of posts, where a user's posts would always have to be moderated by a superuser unless they are a "verified" user (User.verified = true)

I was going to setup a boolean column in the User model, :verified and if that is true, then allow them to post and circumvent moderation.

So, when the user would go to post... I know i could easily set up a hidden field for a post. For example, in my post form, I could add

```
<%= f.hidden_field :approved, :value => 1 if current_user.verified == 1 %>
```

However, i know this is not secure, and anyone could easily use firebug to modify this.

What is the best practice to move this logic into the model/controller, or is there a good resource link that covers this sort of thing, overriding or modifying the "default" create/update actions?

thanks

Per the answer below, here is what i have now in my Post model:

```
#If user is verified, set approved column to true
before_save :check_for_verified

def check_for_verified
    approved = user.verified?
end
```

However, its not allowing me to save now, it doesn't error, just doesnt allow the save.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your feeling that this does not belong in the view is correct.

There are lots of ways you could go about this.  One way would be to set up a before_create callback on the model that sets approved if the user is verified

```
class Post

before_create :approve_if_user_verified

def approve_if_user_verified
  approved = user.verified?
end
```

Comment: Is there a more general before_save that would work for any modification, on both create/update